# How can I use a Xamarin DataTemplate with an ObservableCollection instead of a List?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a page that looks like this. I tested out the code using a List but I need to use an ObservableCollection as the contents of the data will change after it's initially populated. My problem is that when I change from a List to ObservableCollection I no longer see any data appearing.

```
    public YourPage()
    {
    
      var viewModel = _vm = new YourPageViewModel()

      var dataTemplate = new DataTemplate(()=>
      {
         var mygrid = new MyGrid ();
         mygrid.SetBinding(MyGrid.TextProperty, "Text");
         return mygrid;
      });
      StackLayout stackLayout = new StackLayout();
      BindableLayout.SetItemsSource(stackLayout, _vm.ListOfText);
      BindableLayout.SetItemTemplate(stackLayout, dataTemplate);
      Content = stackLayout;
   }

   protected override void OnAppearing()
   {
      base.OnAppearing();
     _vm.OnAppearing();
   }
```

And a ViewModel

```
  public partial class YourPageViewModel : BaseViewModel
  {
 
     private ObservableCollection<TestModel> _listOfText;

     public ObservableCollection<TestModel> ListOfText{
        get => _listOfText;
        set => SetProperty(ref _listOfText, value);
     }

     public void OnAppearing()
     {
            var tempList = ...;
            ListOfText = new ObservableCollection<TestModel>(tempList);
     }
  }
```

Given this situation with an ObservableCollection then the data template doesn't seem to show any data.

Does anyone have an idea what might be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solutions given work for when the data is populate one time after the binding is set up but then after that the layout will not be refreshed.

To solve this problem what is needed is to place the DataTemplate in a CollectionView

```
  CollectionView collectionView = new CollectionView();
  collectionView.SetBinding(ItemsView.ItemsSourceProperty, "ListOfText");
  collectionView.ItemTemplate =  new DataTemplate(() =>
  {
     var mygrid = new MyGrid ();
     mygrid.SetBinding(MyGrid.TextProperty, "Text");
     return mygrid;
  });
  Content = collectionView;
```

When this is done the ObservableCollection can be refreshed at any time and the screen layout will change when it's refreshed.

Answer (score 1):

You will want to create the `ObservableCollection` only once. If you use data-binding on it, it will subscribe to certain events that will emit the changes in the collection.

By doing `ListOfText = new ObservableCollection<TestModel>(tempList);` it will cause those events to be disconnected and your data won't show up. Instead, change it to be more like this

```cs
public partial class YourPageViewModel : BaseViewModel
  {
     // This changed
     private ObservableCollection<TestModel> _listOfText = new ObservableCollection<TestModel>(tempList);

     public ObservableCollection<TestModel> ListOfText{
        get => _listOfText;
        set => SetProperty(ref _listOfText, value);
     }

     public void OnAppearing()
     {
            var tempList = ...;

            // This changed
            ListOfText.Clear();

            foreach (var text in tempList)
                ListOfText.Add(text);
     }
  }
```

Notice how I only create the `ObservableCollection` once and repopulate each time instead of creating a new one.

Comment: Thanks very much.  I will check this out.  Also I noticed when I moved the population of the collection to the Constructor and out of the OnAppearing then the list was populated.

Comment: Your comment makes perfect sense and fixes the problem just like Leo's suggestion.  However for this app I didn't change the ViewModel code but just changed the XAML to C# for the front-end.  In the ViewModel I have code like this: ListOfText = new ObservableCollection<TestModel>(temp) {[0] = {Selected = true}}; and even after the initial binding this still works and changes the data being shown.  Do you have any idea why it would work in XAML and not in C# back-end (which looks the same to me).

Comment: Without seeing the rest of the code that is almost impossible to say. There are some differences in how XAML is initialized as opposed to how C# is initialized. Both can do the same thing and should mostly work the same, but you might've hit an edge case here.

If one of the answers helped, don't forget to mark them as an answer!

Answer (score 1):

Becasue when you set the data-binding in the constructor of your page,the `ListOfText` is not populated the data until you call  `_vm.OnAppearing();` in `OnAppearing()` method.

You could try to pipulate the data in the constructor of your viewmodel:

```
public partial class YourPageViewModel : BaseViewModel
{

 private ObservableCollection<TestModel> _listOfText;

 public ObservableCollection<TestModel> ListOfText{
    get => _listOfText;
    set => SetProperty(ref _listOfText, value);
 }
 public YourPageViewModel ()
 {
    var tempList = ...;
    _listOfText = new ObservableCollection<TestModel>(tempList);
 }
}
```

and then you don't need to call  `_vm.OnAppearing();` in `OnAppearing()` method.
You need to make sure that you have populated your data when you bind it.

Comment: I just added a message to the comment by Gerald. Your explanation makes sense and I can use that.  But, do you have any idea why this would work when the page layout is done in XAML.  I even have another XAML data template on the page and that refreshes with ListOfMeanings = new ObservableCollection<TestModel>(temp); which is executed when I tap on an entry in the first DataTemplate list.

Comment: You mention "You need to make sure that you have populated your data when you bind it."   However in the XAML code it's bound just once but later on the list is refreshed with a different number of rows and the number of the rows on the screen changes.  How can I get this to happen?